# PHPMailer not redirecting after submit

Tags: php, phpmailer

The code works correctly in sending the mail and auto reply to the visitor. However when the form is submitted the page does nothing and just sits on the same page with the form still filled out. It is not redirecting to browser to the "Thank you" page.

I have spend hours on trying to resolve this and cant for the life of me figure out why it wont redirect.

Please someone help!

```
<?php
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/class.phpmailer.php';
session_start();

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$time = date("d/m/y @ H:i:s", time());
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$sendfrom = "admin@example.com";
$sendname = "Senders Name";

$name = $_POST['visitor-name'];
$subject = $_POST['visitor-subject'];
$email = $_POST['visitor-email'];
$message = $_POST['visitor-message'];
$phone = $_POST['visitor-phone'];

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->IsSMTP(true);
$mail->Host = "localhost"; //Hostname of the mail server
$mail->Port = '25'; //Port of the SMTP like to be 25, 80, 465 or 587
$mail->ClearReplyTos();
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
$mail->SetFrom($sendfrom, $name); //FROM address and NAME
$mail->AddAddress($sendfrom); //TO address
$mail->Subject = ("Web Form: $subject");
$mail->Body = "MESSAGE";
$mail->IsHTML(true);

//auto reply
if($mail->send()){
    $automail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $automail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $automail->IsSMTP(true);
    $automail->Host = "localhost"; //Hostname of the mail server
    $automail->Port = '25'; //Port of the SMTP like to be 25, 80, 465 or 587
    $automail->ClearReplyTos();
    $automail->addReplyTo("sales@example.com", $sendname);
    $automail->SetFrom($sendfrom, $sendname); //FROM address and NAME
    $automail->AddAddress($email); //TO address
    $automail->Subject = "Thank you for your recent enquiry";
    $automail->Body = "AUTO REPLY MESSAGE";

    $automail->IsHTML(true);

if($automail->Send()) {
    Header("Location: success.php");
    exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: check error.log if any output was sent!

Comment: no error log, the mail is being sent correctly and even the auto reply sends fine too.

Comment: Header() only works if no output was sent! so mail could be sent but a notice or what ever could be sent and redirect will not work ... so check error.log, set display_errors on .... check if you run in if($automail->Send())

Comment: Do you mean that `$automail->Send()` returns `false` but the message gets sent anyway? Or you just don't know? Is your server configured to display/log all error messages?

Comment: Someone left a comment, asking me to try

if($automail->Send()) {
echo "<script> parent.self.location='success.php'; </script>";
    }

Which worked great!

Comment: I'll use a simile: you're building a house and you can't figure out why your front door doesn't fit. So you put a curtain instead.

Comment: Do you know how to verify what `$automail->Send()` returns or whether your server is configured to display errors? Do you need help on that?

Comment: server is configured to return errors, i have looked into the log file when i received error regarding SMTP auth but that was separate issue. I dont get any error when i submit my original code, just does not redirect the header.

Comment: You are using an old version of PHPMailer and have based your code on an old example. You don't need to create a new instance to send a second message. You're specifying that it should throw exceptions, but then you're not using try/catch to deal with it. You're not displaying any error output that PHPMailer provides - display the contents of `$mail->ErrorInfo` for a start.

Answer (score 1):

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

That helped me